# Failed to establish a connection to the remote server at mysite.com Coinbase Commerce Webhook

Tags: node.js, api, payment-gateway, coinbase-api, coin-change

I have been trying to integrate the coinbase commerce payment gateway into my node js application for a week now, but I have a problem with the webhook sending back a response. I have contacted the coin base support and was told they would get back to me but its over five days now and still no response. This is my code to generate a charge and it works perfectly;

```
router.post("/createCharge", middlewareObj.isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
  cors(req, res, async () => {
    const chargeData = {
      name: "Test Product",
      description: "You about to make payment  for Test Product",
      local_price: {
        amount: req.body.amount,
        currency: "USD",
      },
      pricing_type: "fixed_price",
    };
    
    const charge = await Charge.create(chargeData);

    res.redirect(charge.hosted_url);
  });
});
```

And this how I handle the response currently, so that I can see what coinbase sends back and then make changes to my code accordingly;

```
router.post("/hook", (req, res) => {
  const rawBody = req.rawBody;
  const signature = req.headers["x-cc-webhook-signature"];
  const webhookSecret = "******";

  try {
    const event = Webhook.verifyEventBody(rawBody, signature, webhookSecret);

    console.log(rawBody);
    res.send(rawBody);
    // res.send(`success ${event.id}`);
  } catch (error) {
    functions.logger.error(error);
    res.status(400).send("failure!");
  }
});
```

I tired sending a test event but I keep getting this error "Failed to establish a connection to the remote server at *mysite". I even tried testing with $10 worth of DAI but the DAI never got to my balance and I have been battling with this and coinbase isn't proving helpful, please what am I doing wrong?